# is there a way to implement the X-Robots-Tag instruction with tomcat?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, heroku, x-robots-tag

I want to add `X-Robots-Tag noindex, nofollow` to the HTTP response of all the .PDF files of a site to avoid that these documents be referenced by the Google search engine.

This is for Tomcat 8 server on Heroku with Spring boot 2.1. From the past, I've tried on Apache Server and the `noindex` and `nofollow` worked well.

```
<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a servlet filter that does this for you like.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"*.pdf"})
public class PdfFilter implements Filter {

    @Override 
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
         httpServletResponse.addHeader("X-Robots-Tag", ""noindex, nofollow");

         chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```